# How to integrate manually CCAvenue Payment Gateway in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

How to integrate manually CCAvenue Payment Gateway

Comment: you need to create payment method for this one according to magento standard.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Kingsman-The-Secret-Service/Magento2-Ccavenue-Payment-Gateway-Module

Download / Install and Configure with your website